# How to assign integer into function called by pthread_create?

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu

Given the following code :

```
void* actThread(int acc)
{
.
.
.
}
int err;
err = pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, actThread,  &connfd);
```

how do i pass the connfd integer into the function actThread. each way I try I get errors

Answer (score 2):

You can do following:

```
void* actThread(void* accp)
{
   int acc = (int)accp;
.
.
.
}
int connfd;
int err;
err = pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, actThread,  (void*)connfd);
```

But, as I assume you have no idea what are you doing, try to learn something about pointers before applying this.

I can recommend you this question for beginning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016765/tutorial-on-c-pointers

Answer (score 2):

Usually a thread created by phtread_create has type `void* function (void*)`. A void pointer can point to any kind of instance thus also a integer. Take the next example it shows how to increment an integer asynchronously.

```
void* increment (void * pointer_to_int)
{
    int* number = (int*) pointer_to_int;
    (*number)++;
    return number;
}
```

then you might call the thread like this:

```
pthread_t t;
int *no_answer = malloc(sizeof(int));
//check if you get an int
*no_answer = 41;

pthread_create(&t, NULL, increment, (void*)no_answer);
pthread_join(t, NULL);
printf("The answer is %d\n", *no_answer);
free(no_answer);
```

you first allocate an int and put it to a certain value the above increments it in the thread. you might even get the return value with pthread_join, however it would be a bit redundant in this code.

EDIT the code outputs `The answer is 42`

Comment: Note that here you could simply do `int no_answer = 41; pthread_create(&t, NULL, increment, (void*)&no_answer);` :)

Comment: @Pragmateek You are absolutely right, however many times one just send some data to a thread and have the thread do operations to that data however the instance should be freed in the thread then.

Comment: I was more concerned about the possibility of the local memory to go out of scope if the function ends before the thread has finished using the data. But here, as the function joins the thread, the memory location will remain valid at least until the end of the thread. :)